# C# WPF - How to auto refresh the UI after run it

Tags: c#, wpf, refresh

I created in the XAML a simple `Label` called `TbTimer`

I made the following code:

```
class Level2 
{
    public Level2()
    {
        timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
    }
    public int counter;
    public void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        counter++;
    }

    public DispatcherTimer timer;
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        lvl2 = new Level2();
    }

    private void MenuItemMedium_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        lvl2.timer.Start();
        TbTimer.Content = lvl2.counter.ToString();
    }
}
```

Then I have another button, and I call `TimerUpdater` when that button is clicked.

When I run the program and I click the button, I can see that the content of the `TextBlock` shows the number 1... and it does not continue to run the numbers - when I click the button again after 5 seconds it shows the number 6.

So I guess the timer is running fine behind the scenes, but the content of the `TextBlock` is updated only when I click the button.

What should I do to make the `TextBlock` content update the seconds without clicking the button? Hope my explanation and question is clear.

Comment: You have to update the label on timertick, not just increment an unrelated variable. Ps: you've got a method in a method.

Comment: Thank you Jeroen, but... how do i update the textblock on the timertick? i eam pretty new in this, hope you can guid me

Comment: I'm not entirely sure but `Dispatcher.Invoke(() => TbTimer.Text = counter);` should be about it (inside your `Timer_Tick` method).

Comment: I don't think `Dispatcher.Invoke` would be necessary in this case as a `DispatcherTimer` is being used, so the callback should fire in the UI thread (I believe).

Comment: i wrote the dispatcher.invoke but the system ask me for "delegate method" which i am not familiar with... any suggestions?

Comment: Personally I would make the class `Level2` inherit `INotifyPropertyChanged`, then I would change `counter` to a property that raises change notifications, and finally I would *bind* `TbTimer.Content` to `lvl2.Counter`. Then anytime the Counter property is updated, the UI will also automatically update. That's the proper way to do it in WPF :)

Comment: @Rachel, an excellent point. I included that as the "right" way to do it in my answer.

Comment: Thank you Rachel, and thank you Bradley! your code works for me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your modified code, the answer changes completely. I apologize for the dramatic change in content. The "simplest" way to accomplish this would be to add an event for the counter updating and have your UI subscribe to it. Something like:

```
class Level2
{
    public event Action<int> CounterUpdated;

    ...
    public void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        counter++;
        if (CounterUpdated != null)
           CounterUpdated(counter);
    }
}

public class MainWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
       InitializeComponent();

       lvl2 = new Level2();
       lvl2.CounterUpdated += UpdateCounterText;
    }

    private void MenuItemMedium_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       lvl2.timer.Start();
    }

    private void UpdateCounterText(int newCounterValue)
    {
        TbTimer.Content = newCounterValue.ToString();
    }
}
```

Incidentally, this ends up being similar to how the binding system is set up. If you just bound your textbox to the `counter` variable, it would be much cleaner and easier to use. To do that, you would change your XAML to:

```
<TextBox Name="TbTimer" Text="{Binding Counter}"/>
```

and assign the DataContext:

```
public class MainWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
       InitializeComponent();

       lvl2 = new Level2();
       DataContext = lvl2;
    }

    private void MenuItemMedium_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        lvl2.timer.Start();
    }
}
```

`Level2` now needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged, and you have to make counter a property (so it can be bound to):

```
class Level2 : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //Notify Property Changed Implementation from MSDN:
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
           PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    private int counter = 0;
    public int Counter
    {
       get { return counter; }
       set
       {
           counter = value;
           NotifyPropertyChanged();
       }
    }

    ...
    public void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Counter++;
    }
}
```

The binding system will now update the text box automatically when the timer ticks (and increments the `Counter` property. This is the way it **should** be done in WPF, so feel free to ask any questions that come up when implementing it.

For reference, this is the implemenation of `INofityPropertyChanged` I used: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx

Comment: The TimerUpdater is in a different class, he is not in the MainWindow, so i can't add "    TbTimer.Text = counter.ToString();   " under the counter because the class does not recognize the UI in the new class... also tried to add the "IF" you gave me but it still not working

Comment: @user3396397 so how did your code work in the first place? From what you have shown, my code will compile. I'm willing to change it, but you'll have to show some more code/details.

Comment: I just edited my code above... please look at it, hope you will be able to assist. of course there are more code in the MAIN but it is not relevant for the TIMER issue. also i changed the textblock to label (just thought it will be easier to habdle... but it is not)

Comment: @user3396397, Thanks I'll look at in a bit and get back to you.

Comment: Thank you for your time, waiting for your feedback :)

Comment: @user3396397, There you go, let me know if it helps!

Comment: If you didn't use the (second) MVVM way, do look into it. It will make your life in WPF much easier :)